# Setting custom backbutton on uinavigationbar iphone, some times results with backbutton on top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Hello i've checked some posts but couldn't find any useful info on my problem. I've successfully added a button but sometimes backbutton appears on top.

My code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton backButton];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(popView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtn;
[barBtn release];
```

result:

[image]

So maybe someone had some similar problems or knows what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At what point are you calling this code ? It should be at `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: This links worked for me: http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/12/how-do-iphone-apps-instagramreederdailybooth-implement-custom-navigationbar-with-variable-width-back-buttons/, http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=401

Comment: @adig I added this in viewdidload, but now when i moved to viewwillappear it doesn't help either..

Comment: Lukas check my asnwer below same problem was with me but I solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found what was it. There was some problems with navigation controller and presenting view controllers, so after fixing them this bug is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You need change some code...I have put some code here.

```
   UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
            [leftButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"leftbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
            leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
            [leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(youraction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];

       [leftButton release];
```

Hope, this may help you..

Comment: i have a categorie that im using which returns a button for me:
UIButton *btn = [UIButton backButton];

everything else is the same, thanks for trying to help, but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem..

Comment: yes..but it's good that if you use this customization. you just need to only beck button image and that will saveyour lot's of time

Comment: I'm using a lot of this backbutton, so i made a categorie, the categorie saves me a lot of time, when i need this button i just write UIButton *btn = [UIButton backButton]; and thats it.

Answer (score 1):

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

Should solve your problem

Comment: But isn't it the same as this?
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

Comment: Hmm well it should actually be the same.. odd that it still shows!

Answer (score 1):

Hi lukas you can use below code as it works fine for me....

UINavigationBar *bar;
     UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bak.png"];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

```
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(popView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

    customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=customBarItem;
    [bar addSubview:button];
```

let me know if you need any clarification....